# jsonp call: missing ) after argument list

Tags: java, ajax, jsonp

I am calling a rest API through Jsonp. The API server returns the right value, but I am getting 'missing ) after argument list' and ajax returns error. What is not correct here?

In Javascript,

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:8080/version',
dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'GET',
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
error: function(xhr, status, error){
     console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText)
},
```

});

In Java,

```
@GET
@Produces("application/javascript")
public String getVersion(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
      return callback + "(hello)";
}
```

Comment: Show the actual JSONP text that generated the error. Your Java code produces something incorrect, but not incorrect in the way that the error message suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how you'd get *that* error, but the JSONP response is wrong. You're sending back something like this:

```
callbackName(hello)
```

That expects a global `hello` variable; hello should be in quotes:

```
callbackName("hello")
```

So:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/javascript")
public String getVersion(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
      return callback + "(\"hello\")";
// NOTE ------------------^^-----^^
}
```

Regarding

> missing ) after argument list

This is the kind of thing that would produce that error:

```
callbackName("hello"
```

or a missing `,` between arguments would also produce it:

```
callbackName("hi" "there")
```